# angularjs requirejs routeprovider stuck on main page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using requirejs with angular and I cannot get the Route provider to work:

```
require.config({

// alias libraries paths
paths: {
    'angular': 'vendor/angular.min',
    'angularRoute': 'vendor/angular-route'
},

// angular does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
shim: {
    'angular': {exports: 'angular'},
    'angularRoute':['angular']
},
priority: ["angular"]
});
require([
     'angular',
     'app'
     ],
    function(angular, app){
        'use strict';
        var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
        angular.element().ready(function() {
        $html.addClass('ng-app');
        angular.bootstrap($html, [app['name']]);
        app.config(['$routeProvider',
                    function($routeProvider){
                        $routeProvider.when('/',{
                            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                            controller:'MyCtrl1'
                        })
                        .when('/views2',{
                            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                            controller:'MyCtrl2'
                        })
                        .otherwise({
                            templateUrl: 'views/dontknow',
                            controller:'MyCtrl2'
                        })
                    }
        ]);
}); 
})
```

My base app URL looks like following: http://example.com:8080/HOMEPAGE/
When I type in http://example.com:8080/HOMEPAGE/#views2 shouldnt this try and pull the home.html?

My controller looks like following:

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
'use strict';
var myController = angular.module('myController', []);
myController.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = "hello world";
    }]).controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = "hello world2";
    }]);
return myController;

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't your url be http://example.com:8080/HOMEPAGE/views2? also try removing the first relative path. So http://example.com:8080/views2.

Comment: Does everything work fine if you visit http://example.com:8080/HOMEPAGE/?

Comment: @bekite yes everything loads up correctly when i first visit the homepage

Comment: @MarcoFranssen [link](example.com:8080/Homepage) is the main page I have setup with angular. I tried creating absolute URL without any luck

Comment: did you try http://example.com:8080/HOMEPAGE/#/views2 ?

Comment: maybe you could create a jsfiddle / plunker that shows the error?

Comment: I created this plunkr -  http://plnkr.co/edit/BqfKhhAvmpQQlVqQJHjB?p=catalogue --i didnt add all the dependencies but added my main files if that helps.

Comment: I found the root of the problem in my app. I had not defined <div ngview><div> to display the results of my controller.

Answer (score 2):

I found the root of the problem in my app. I had not defined

```
<div ng-view>

</div>
```

to display the results of my controller